# Can a water supply line be routed downward to clear a joist?

Tags: plumbing, water

My water line runs along a double joist.  I want to run new supply line(s) (for bathroom) up through ceiling on the other side of joist.

Is there any reason–code or otherwise–not to do an end-run down and around the joist? That is, can I run line downward for a few inches?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that bring it below the level of the ceiling?

Comment: Tetsujin, this is unfinished room in basement. There  is no "ceiling" under the joists. Regarding finishing in the future, this won't be the first pipe below joist level.

Comment: Added picture. Please forgive cereal, but use as reference! Water lines currently on the right through floor. Want to move to left of joists (with drain pipe) behind wall.

Comment: @manasseh The two of you get confused for each other all the time IRL, so why not here too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, there's no problem with that. Supply lines do not have the constraints that drains and vents do of needing to maintain a given slope.

There can be issues in specific cases, but those can be addressed (i.e. if the run under the joist puts the pipe closer than 1.5" to (but hidden under) the ceiling below, you need protective plates to prevent drilling into the pipe. If the pipe is exposed on the surface, you don't need those as it's presumed you can see the pipe and not drill into it. If it's more than 1.5" from the ceiling you don't need protective plates.

If the pipe was in a seasonal unheated building, the water trapped (and unable to be drained) in that section of the line might cause problems by freezing in the off-season. In a year round house that's generally not a concern, or you have bigger problems if it *becomes* a concern. A well-thought-out seasonal dwelling does put intentional slopes in the supply lines to facilitate effective draining before the off-season.

Drilling a hole though the center ("the center" from top to bottom - hole going from side to side) of the joist is generally also an acceptable method, as that portion (the "neutral axis" structurally) is relatively low-stress, and supply lines are generally small in proportion to joists.

Answer (score 2):

Breakfast cereal is forgiven: it's one of my favorite kinds too!

There are tees sending the water up through the floor to the right of the double joist now. You're asking whether you could cut those riser pipes and route them back down below the joist and up on the left side?

Well, yes, you could do that. But it's going to add at least 4 elbows to the path. Elbows impede water flow. While some number of elbows are unavoidable, this routing does seem a little excessive.

You could instead re-arrange the 3/4" trunk pipes. Figure out where a tee should go so that the new pipes rise up in the right place. Cut the trunk pipe there and also cut off the existing riser pipes. Remove the existing 3/4x1/2 tee right of the doubled joists together with the cut stubs of 3/4 and 1/2 pipe and flip it around so that the tee is left of the doubled joists. Re-install the section with a no-stop coupler to repair the 3/4 trunk pipe.